# CakePHP with TinyMce Editor: Numbered and bulleted lists not appearing in view.ctp

Tags: css, cakephp, tinymce

I have the TinyMce editor tied to a couple of longtext fields in an edit.ctp file. When I create bulleted or numbered lists, they appear correctly in edit.ctp, but in view.ctp, they appear without bullets or numbers. They're just stacks of left-justified text. All other special formatting (e.g., bold, italic, underline, indentations, etc.) displays correctly in view.ctp. Is there something I need to do to the field in my View to get the bullets/numbers to show up?

Examples of the problem:

Content in TinyMCE editor embedded in my edit.ctp:

[image]

The same content in my view.ctp

[image]

I have tried using html_entity_decode to no avail.

Comment: Check the applied CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was traced to my cake.generic.css file. The styling was incorrect there. Upon correction, the bullets and numbered lists appeared correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving style externally using CSS or jQuery. Because `<ul>` and `<li>` tags must have stored in database. Like:

CSS :

```
ul{
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( ul).css( "list-style-type", "circle" );
```